# What's the correct way of consulting the number of open files on a Linux system

Tags: linux

What's the correct way of consulting the number of open files on a Linux system. I know that both sysctl fs.file-nr, cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr and lsof can report this number. The problem that in my case lsof is reporting a huge number in comparison with the fs.file-nr. Looks like lsof is showing duplicate entries: the same file descriptor appears several times but for different threads.

Comment: Depends on if you want to know open file handles or the number of actual files that have been opened. What is the purpose you need to know this number?

Comment: get the number of file descriptors in use

Comment: Yes, but where are you going to use this number?